# Does the Lyre of Building generate the building materials?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

The [Lyre of Building](http://archivesofnethys.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Lyre%20of%20Building) can be used to do building work. I assume that the materials need to be provided but I am not sure, hence the question.

> ...that magically construct buildings, mines, tunnels, ditches, etc. The effect produced in 30 minutes of playing is equal to the work of 100 humans laboring for 3 days.

Does the Lyre create buildings from nothing or do building materials need to be provided?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it's not clearly stated in the description of the magic item, I'd say that you would need to provide the building materials.

This is due to several aspects of the description. First is the fact that it specifically states that it reproduces the labour generated. Secondly, that it doesn't state that it generates the building etc from nothing (or by magic). Lastly, other spells and/or magic items, that reproduces stuff, clearly mentions this in their description. As well as the upper value cap of the materials produced.

So, in short: The item as written only specifies that it replaces the workforce, not the raw materials.

Comment: What if you use the workforce to acquire raw materials? 100 labourers can cut down a lot of trees or quarry a fair amount of stone in three days!

Comment: The Lyre doesn't provide a workforce, but an effect (building structures) comparable to what a similarly sized workforce would accomplish in the specified time period. As I stated in my answer to the related question, it really depends upon what the DM allows due to the act of "construction" can be rather widely defined. See: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/89433/31843

Comment: Two other things of note: (1) It has Fabricate as a prerequisite, not Minor/Major Creation (2) its aura is Transmutation, not Conjuration